# Next/Done button placement is inconsistent in iPhone Virtual Keyboad with Codename One

Tags: ios, iphone, codenameone

When using [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/)'s text fields as such:

```
TextField field1 = new TextField(30);
TextField field2 = new TextField(30);
```

I get the following two virtual keyboards:

[image: With Done on top]

[image: With Done below]

This is inconsistent behavior as the Done option moves between positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the toolbar entry that includes the "Done" button for an individual entry by using:

```
field1.putClientProperty("iosHideToolbar", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Once this is set the toolbar won't appear.

The logic for having this is consistency where you can let the user explicitly press the "DONE" button which is normally not accessible. The Done/Next buttons are platform conventions and iOS doesn't have the ability to stick both into the keyboard.

The Done button can be bound to an event using [setDoneListener](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/TextField.html#setDoneListener-com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener-) on the `TextField` component.

Comment: Thanks Shai, this has been so annoying in some of my apps and I thought it's a normal behaviour on iOS which doesn't have a workaround and is not worth asking. Where can we get up-to-date Build-hints, theme constants and ClientProperties?

Comment: The theme constants and build hint list should be pretty complete in the developer guide. If you see something missing there then let us know. Client properties are a special case though since they are component/command specific and don't make as much sense in a single global list. This should be documented in the TextArea/Field sections of the developer guide and their respective JavaDocs.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog if I set this field1.putClientProperty("iosHideToolbar", Boolean.TRUE); hide Done Button from toolbar but appear in keyboard?

Comment: Notice this only applies to the top "Done" button. Not to the one in the keyboard itself